# Actually Centering a tikzpicture on the page under a subsection

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

**EDIT: I adjusted the margin of the whole document which somewhat solves the problem, but I would still appreciate a more elegant fix.**

I'm new to LaTeX, so sorry if this is a super simple issue. I've looked everywhere but I can't find any solutions, but again, I'm new.

I'm organizing my file with sections, subsections, etc., and I'm making a tikz graph out of nodes. The actual creation of the graph is fine, but it has the same offset as everything else under the subsection and I'm running out of room. Is there any way to center the graph in the page or somehow try to keep everything visible?

Here is my base code:

```
\section{Structure Overview}
        \subsection{Path Graph}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[
                % Define Node Types
                ]

                % Draw Nodes

                % Draw Edges
            \end{tikzpicture}
```

I've also tried the same thing with `centering`:

```
\section{Structure Overview}
        \subsection{Path Graph}
            {\centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}[
                    % Define Node Types
                    ]

                    % Draw Nodes

                    % Draw Edges
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
```

and with `\begin{center}`:

```
\section{Structure Overview}
        \subsection{Path Graph}
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[
                    % Define Node Types
                    ]

                    % Draw Nodes

                    % Draw Edges
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{center}
```

All of them have the same alignment issue and all of them are in almost the exact same position on the page. Both the `\centering` solution and the `\begin{center}` solution move the graph to the left a hair, but there is plenty of room available to the left of the leftmost node and the rightmost node is off the page regardless of which one I compile.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Tip: Add the showframe package to better see the coordinate system.

Comment: Great tip! Thanks! I still have the same issue, obviously, but this is super helpful!

Comment: Although this differs according to document class, often a `\subsection` is "run in".  That is, it expects that there will be some text immediately following it.  Therefore, you can try to trick it by inserting something invisible in that position.  Try this:  `\subsection{Path Graph} {\ }` and follow that by a blank line.  Then `{\centering ...}` should give the result you want.  (This isn't an answer since we don't know what document class you're using.)

Comment: In addition to @Dr.ManuelKuehner's comment, add at the very end of the `tikzpicture` `\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);`. It might be that the bounding box gets overestimated, in which case it might help to load `\usetikzlibrary{bbox}` and add `bezier bounding box` to the options of the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: Problem solved?